# Is it possible to use SASL authentication with Kafka clients but not require it for Zookeeper?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, sasl

I've followed this: http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/sasl.html#sasl-configuration-for-kafka-brokers

To configure SASL authentication to my Kafka cluster. I'd like to have all my clients authenticate to the brokers through SASL. I don't care about kafka<->zookeeper. The reason is I need to create ACL's in Kafka. The issue arises when starting the Kafka cluster and receiving an error about not being able to authenticate to Zookeeper:

> SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException:
>   No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified
>   JAAS configuration file: '/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf'. Will
>   continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication,
>   if Zookeeper server allows it.
>       Opening socket connection to server zk-2.zookeeper-service.default.svc.cluster.local/100.96.16.2:2181
>       Error occurred while connecting to Zookeeper server[zk-0.zookeeper-service:2181,zk-1.zookeeper-service:2181,zk-2.zookeeper-service:2181].
>   Authentication failed.

I haven't configured Zookeeper for SASL authentication and would rather avoid if I could. Is this possible at all?

Comment: This isn't really on-topic here, but it's also not in good shape for migration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out the specific docker image I was basing my config off of (confluentinc/cp-kafka:3.2.1) assumes that Zookeeper will be SASL enabled if Kafka is (https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/3.2.x/debian/base/include/cub#L99)

It passes the same JAVA flag by default to the `io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.ZookeeperReadyCommand` which you can optionally disable by setting the `ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED` to false.

Comment: put FALSE in upper case, it took me a while to figure out that. it doesn work on lower.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly my issue. 
ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED="false" made it

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to leave ZooKeeper out of SASL configuration. Please take a look at [this document](https://developer.ibm.com/opentech/2017/05/31/kafka-acls-in-practice/) for a basic SASL setup. I hope it helps.